# Side by Side Div not Aligned in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to iterating a divs in a row with ng-repeat ,every row contains 2 div, if i collapse left side div ,right side div should comes below left side div but its not working.
Here is my Code Below :

```
<div class="row>
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-6" ng-repeat="g in list">
          <div>..content..</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Any CSS tricks ?

Comment: try to use `float:left;width:50%` in your div class

Comment: tried it already Manoj, but its not working

Comment: Give your left div "float:left;, and your right div "float:right", place both of them inside a parent div, whenever you get one collapsed the other takes the place, this can solve the issue

Comment: Not working Neo..Need some other logic i guess

Comment: where are the 2 divs in your HTML? All I see are nested divs

Comment: i have given every div a col-md-6 , so in every row only 2 div will be placed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="row clearfix>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-6" ng-repeat="g in list">
              <div>..content..</div>
          </div>
    </div>


    .clearfix {
        zoom: 1;
    }
    
        .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
            line-height: 0;
        }
    
        .clearfix:after {
            clear: both;
        }
```

It will work definitely.

Comment: Nope..still having a same issue .